# Android: Implementing a VoIP program

Tags: android, udp, voip, skype

I have some design questions that I want to discuss with people interested in helping me. I am planning to develop a simple VoIP program that allows two Android phones in the same network to use VoIP. My goal is simply to capture sound, send the data with UDP, receive UDP data and play sound.

My current design is to have 2 threads: one captures the microphone and sends the data; the other one receives bytes and plays them.

I was starting to implement that using MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder. The issue that came up is how do I record and play sound? By that, I would like to know if I need to use a file, although that seems slow, or if there is anyway to have the recording automatically sent to my UDP socket please?

Basically, I wonder if I have to record to a file, then to be able to play it, or if I could just pass a socket (for recording and playing).

Does anyone has any suggestion please?

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "phones in the same network" aren't all these devices on the internet?

Comment: By same network I mean that it doesn't go out of the NAT box (that's those Linksys router for example). The issue would be the firewall: an incoming connection would be rejected because it doesn't know which device to forward it to and also for security reasons. For this reason, all the devices will be all connected to the same router for my first step, and I will manually enter IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

MediaRecorder needs an FD so, you can use sockets as well. I dont see any issues with that. It all depends on how you would design your system.

Comment: When I use the "Socket" class, I can pass the socket to the MediaRecorder, but the Socket class uses TCP, it seems. I've been trying to use the DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket classes as it uses UDP, but the MediaRecorder will not take those classes. I was using ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket() but it requires a Socket, not a DatagramSocket. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use those classes for streaming audio - use AudioTrack and AudioRecord instead.

They provide the functionality you need for playing and recording raw audio data, without dealing with an FD.

When you record a frame (either byte[] or short[]), wrap it with a UDP packet.
When you receive a UDP packet, unpack the relevant byte[] or short[] and play it.